# *Right* outer join in LINQ

Tags: linq

Is it safe to say that there is no such thing as a right outer join in LINQ?

I know to effectively create one, you'd just swap the tables in a left outer join.  But can you apply the DefaultIfEmpty() method to the table on the left side of the equijoin to make it a right outer join?

Comment: A right outer join is an inner join union the non matching entities from the right collection, this is feasible in LINQ. I believe your question is more: *Is there a LINQ construction which is actually translated by LINQ to `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` SQL? like there is one, `GroupJoin()` + `SelectMany()` with `DefaultIfEmpty()`, which is translated to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After extensive looking, I can find nothing referring to a right outer join.  The only syntax available for an outer join is a left outer join.

Comment: Not entirely true - the only syntax for an outer join is an outer join. There's no 'left' or 'right' join in LINQ.

Comment: @Kirk, if you're saying there is no SQL-like "right" or "left" keyword, you're right, but I think the OP is saying a left outer join is possible, you just use DefaultIfEmpty so that the results can be included.

Comment: Yeah, they'd be equivalent except for the resulting sort order.  If you want to preserve the sort order of the partial left then you're out of luck it seems.