# How to make a right join using LINQ to SQL & C#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a problem creating the following SQL Statement using LINQ & C#

```
    select c.IDAddenda, c.Descripcion
      from CatAddendas c 
right join EmpresaAddenda e on e.IDAddenda = c.IDAddenda
     where e.rfc = 'SUL010720JN8'
  order by c.IDAddenda asc
```

I got this:

```
public IEnumerable<CatAddenda> TraeAddendas(string rfc)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(...);

    return (from adds in dc.EmpresaAddendas
            cats.IDAddenda    into joined 
            where adds.RFC == rfc
            select adds.CatAddenda);
}
```

This is not doing a right join, so any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730810/right-outer-join-in-linq

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 var RightJoin = from adds in dc.EmpresaAddendas
                 join cats in CatAddendas 
                     on adds.IDAddenda equals cats.IDAddenda into joined
                 from cats in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     Id = cats.IDAddenda,
                     Description = cats.Descripcion 
                 };
```

Comment: This is left outer join

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 5):

```
var results = from e in EmpresaAddenda
              join c in CatAddendas
              on e.IDAddenda equals c.IDAddenda into f
              from c in f.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                   ID = c.IDAddenda,
                   Description = c.Descripcion 
              };
```

You can apply where and order by on the results.