# SQL query to linq with right and left joins and nested query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My sql query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  tblProjects.RevID, tblProjects.CEQRNum, tblProjects.ProjectName, GEOCODE.BBL,     tblProjects.BoroID, GEOCODE.BLOCK, GEOCODE.LOT, 
                     tblMilestoneType.MilestoneName, tblMilestone.MilestoneDate
FROM            tblMilestoneType INNER JOIN
                     tblMilestone ON tblMilestoneType.MilestoneID = tblMilestone.MilestoneTypeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     tblProjects ON tblMilestone.RevID = tblProjects.RevID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     GEOCODE ON tblProjects.RevID = GEOCODE.RevID
WHERE        (
            tblMilestone.MilestoneDate IN (SELECT MAX(tblMilestone.MilestoneDate) AS MilestoneDate
                                          FROM tblMilestone INNER JOIN tblMilestoneType ON tblMilestone.MilestoneTypeID = tblMilestoneType.MilestoneID
                                          GROUP BY tblMilestone.RevID)
         )
ORDER BY tblProjects.RevID
```

I am trying to convert this to linq.

So i started with

```
projectList = db.tblMilestoneTypes
                                .Join(db.tblMilestones,
                                    mileType => mileType.MilestoneID,
                                    mile => mile.MilestoneTypeID,
                                    (mileType, mile) => new
                                    {
                                        tblMilestoneType = mileType,
                                        tblMilestone = mile
                                    })
                                .Join(db.tblProjects,                                        
                                    project => project.        // does not work)
```

Also tried

```
projectList = from MilestoneTypeTable in db.tblMilestoneTypes 
                          join MilestoneTable in db.tblMilestones  on MilestoneTypeTable.MilestoneID equals MilestoneTable.MilestoneTypeID
                          rig   // no right or left join.
```

How do i do this 
Neha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914623/how-to-make-a-right-join-using-linq-to-sql-c-sharp   ...oh...look!

Comment: And what problem(s) do you have with your solution?  "Does not work" is not nearly enough information.  What isn't working, specifically?

Comment: My issue is how to do left and right joins and sub query in linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well After a lot of R&D This is what I found out

1. the T-SQL with LEFT OUTER JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN can be converted to one query with only LEFT OUTER JOIN
2. put subquery as a part of join

and here is the query.

```
    var query = from ProjectTable in db.tblProjects
                        from GeoCodeTable in db.GEOCODEs.Where(geo => geo.RevID == ProjectTable.RevID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from MilestoneTable in db.tblMilestones.Where(mile => mile.RevID == GeoCodeTable.RevID && mile.MilestoneDate == db.tblMilestones.OrderBy(x => x.RevID).Select(x => x.MilestoneDate).Max()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from MilestomeTypeTable in db.tblMilestoneTypes.Where(mt => mt.MilestoneID == MilestoneTable.MilestoneTypeID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Milestone = MilestoneTable,
                Project = ProjectTable,
                GeoCode = GeoCodeTable,
                MilestomeType = MilestomeTypeTable 
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try**

```
projectList = from MilestoneTypeTable in db.tblMilestoneTypes
                      join MilestoneTable in db.tblMilestones on MilestoneTypeTable.MilestoneID equals MilestoneTable.MilestoneTypeID into MileStones 
from mileStone in MileStones 
join from projects in db.tblProjects
on mileStone.RevID  equals projects.RevID
select new { MileStoneType = MilestoneTypeTable, MileStones = mileStone , Project = projects };
```