# C# LINQ translation for a SQL query with RIGHT JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got a query in ACCESS and i have to translate this query in C# LINQ.

```
SELECT DETAIL.*, 
       "" AS DBC_ART, 
       A_ENS.ENS_CODE, 
       A_LEA.LEA_ART, 
       A_ART_1.ART_CHA, 
       A_ART_1.ART_ANA, 
       A_ANA_REPART.ANA_CLA2 
FROM (
       (A_LEA RIGHT JOIN 
        ((DETAIL LEFT JOIN A_ART ON DETAIL.DFA_ART = A_ART.ART_CODE)
         LEFT JOIN A_ENS ON DETAIL.DFA_ART = A_ENS.ENS_CODE) ON A_LEA.LEA_ENS = A_ENS.ENS_CODE) 
         LEFT JOIN A_ART AS A_ART_1 ON A_LEA.LEA_ART = A_ART_1.ART_CODE) 
         LEFT JOIN A_ANA_REPART ON A_ART_1.ART_ANA = A_ANA_REPART.ANA_CODE 
WHERE (((A_ENS.ENS_CODE) Is Not Null) AND ((A_ART.ART_CODE) Is Null)) 
ORDER BY DETAIL.BCI, DETAIL.FACTURE;
```

I don't need exactly the `detail` fields as it's detail.* in the query (I'll found the necessary by myself)

It's for the multiple JOIN that i don't know how to translate them.
I've got object lists for each 5 tables

I.E.

Detail -> LstDetail

A_ART -> LstA_ART

A_ENS -> LstA_ENS

A_LEA -> LstA_LEA

A_ART_1 -> LstA_ART (A_ART1 is an alias for another join than with A_ART)

A_ANAREPART -> LstA_ANAREPART

So I begin to write something like :

```
MyList = (from itemDetail in LstDetail 
          join itemART in LstART 
            on itemDetail.DFA_ART equals itemART.ART_CODE 
          join itemANA_REPART in LstANA_REPART 
            on itemART.ART_ANA equals itemANA_REPART.ANA_CODE 
          select (...)).ToList();
```

But I don't know how to handle the right join in the query. Should I make multiple linq queries? What kind?

Thanks in advance for answers

Comment: Have you looked at other examples?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914623/how-to-make-a-right-join-using-linq-to-sql-c-sharp

Comment: A right join is just a left join in the opposite direction, can't you just reorder the query so it is all left joins.  Also if you are doing a left join you will need to use the `DefaultIfEmpty()` syntax otherwise linq treats it as an inner join

Comment: @Bob Vale Your way to transform right join for a left join was the right way, but i was needed to proceed each join separately because i have always got this error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" (I think it was due to joined field with NULL value). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might translate, you may need to adjust case as I've used all lower case.  Additionally you need to choose how to deal with `detail.*`,  either replace the `d...` with a comma separated list of fields from detail `d.field1, d.field2` or something like `detail = d` to allow the detail record to be included as an object.

```
var query = from d in detail
join a1 in a_art on d.dfa_art equals a1.art_code into art
from a in art.DefaultIfEmpty()
join ae1 in a_ens on d.dfa_art equals ae1.ens_code into ens
from ae in ens.DefaultIfEmpty()
join al1 in a_lea on ae.ens_code equals al1.lea_ens into lea
from al in lea.DefaultIfEmpty()
join a2 in a_art on al.art_code equals a2.lea_art into art1
from a1 in art1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join ar1 in a_ana_repart on a1.art_ana equals ar1.ana_code into ana
from ar in ana.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (ae.ens_code != null && a.art_code == null)
select new {
    d...,
    ae.ens_code,
    al.lea_art,
    a1.art_cha,
    a1.art_ana,
    ar.ana_cla2
};
```

Comment: I've simply translated the right join into the corresponding left join

Comment: Right answer : Just need to prefix in object result : ae != null ? ae.ens_code : string.Empty; and so on for the other fields...