# linq dynamic query to also check if a row in linked table exisits

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ query which joins a few tables together and has a dynamic where clause. It works as intended and returns a pre-defined class as a list.

I now have to also join to a table which may not have a row in it - but still bring back the results if the row does not exists.

```
return (from p in db.POInvMasts.AsNoTracking()
             join s in db.POInvMastStatusTypes.AsNoTracking() on p.StatusID equals s.ID
             join po in db.POMasts.AsNoTracking() on p.POMastID equals po.ID
             join v in db.VendMasts.AsNoTracking() on p.VendorID equals v.ID

             //Dynamic link here because there will not always be a carrier at this point
             join c in db.CarrierMasts.AsNoTracking() on p.CarrierID equals c.ID into carriers
             from c in carriers.DefaultIfEmpty()

             //Dynamic link here because there will not always be a GR record at this point
             join gr in db.GRMasts.AsNoTracking() on p.ID equals gr.POInvoiceID into GRs
             from gr in GRs.DefaultIfEmpty()

             where (vendorid == 0 || p.VendorID == vendorid) &&
             (statusid == 0 || p.StatusID == statusid) &&
             (pomastid == 0 || p.POMastID == pomastid) &&
             (grstatusid == 0 || gr.StatusID == grstatusid)

             orderby p.ID
```

Can I do something with the .DefaultIsEmpty? Or can I do something else in the where clause to see if anything in GR exists?

In essence I want to say:

> WHERE gr.StatusID == grstatusid OR gr DOES NOT EXIST.

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks folks!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914623/how-to-make-a-right-join-using-linq-to-sql-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think you want to say left join.. [msdn left join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)