# LINQ Right and Left Joins

Tags: c#, linq

I am practicing LINQ in `LINQ Pad` with `Right, Left and Inner Joins` I notice something

```
(from a in Employees join b in Persons
     on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId into x
     from c in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
select  new {
        a.EmployeeId,
        c.PersonId,
        c.CompleteName
}).Take(50).OrderByDescending(m => m.EmployeeId)
```

and

```
(from a in Persons join b in  Employees
    on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
select new {
    b.EmployeeId,
    b.PersonId,
    a.CompleteName
 }).Take(50).OrderByDescending(m => m.EmployeeId)
```

have the same result.

```
(from a in Persons join b in  Employees
    on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId into x
    from c in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
select 
     new {
        c.EmployeeId,
        c.PersonId,
        a.CompleteName
}).Take(50).OrderByDescending(m => m.EmployeeId)
```

I search for `right and left joins` in linq but my problem is where is the right or left joins in my examples?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all joins in LinQ are `INNER` (Nor right or left).

Your 1st and 3rd query are `LEFT OUTHER JOIN` becouse of `x.DefaultIfEmpty()` line. 2nd - `INNER JOIN`.

1st and 2nd query have same result maby becouse of `.Take(50)`, on your 50 rows could be there is no difference between `INNER` and `OUTHER`.

Comment: I have more than a 200 data. I try to take 50 of it. `1st and 2nd` query have same output. Dunno why.

Comment: @KiRa just get rid off Take and you'll see that 1st jquery LEFT OUTHER and 2nd - INNER

Comment: @KiRa check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9914690/1849444). simple right outher join. The thing is on `from cats in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()` line

Comment: van..I don't really get what is the difference with my example :(. Hard for new learner.

Comment: @KiRa look closer what you join into what (in query). But actually when you using linq you use OUTHER joins really rare

Comment: I think my head gonna explode if I continue to understand it. :'( but thanks. Before I ask a question I saw that link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong in your queries , those looks fine .
To see if there is any changes in `inner join` and `Left join` or `right join`, You have to have data according to that.

If there will be some `Persons` which are not `employees` , will be seen in your first query , and for that yo have to check entire data , `first 50` may not tell you . and same goes for opposite.

Comment: I have more than a 200 data. I try to take 50 of it. 1st and 2nd query have same output. Dunno why

Comment: yes because , whatever data is there in inner join of tables, will be there in `left join` and left join will have additional data with, for that you have to check either by removing `.Take(50)`. or you you can check the count , it will help

Comment: for better understanding look into https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx