# How to apply Right Outer Join using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am facing issue to apply Right Outer Join in LINQ. I am trying to build the similar query in LINQ by converting from SQL query.

My correct SQL query

```
select *
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.FID and t1.CID = 20
right outer join Table3 t3 on t1.GID = t3.GID
```

```
var result = from t1 in Table1
             join t2 in Table2
               on t1.ID equals t2.FID into gr1
             where t1.CID = 20
             join t3 in Table3
               on t1.GID equals t3.GID into gr2
             from t3 in gr2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new Details (){

             }
          return result.ToList();
}
```

My LINQ query is not working as expected to SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

This is also discussed here
[how to make a right join using LINQ to SQL & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914623/how-to-make-a-right-join-using-linq-to-sql-c-sharp)

```
 var RightJoin = from adds in dc.EmpresaAddendas
             join cats in CatAddendas 
                 on adds.IDAddenda equals cats.IDAddenda into joined
             from cats in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 Id = cats.IDAddenda,
                 Description = cats.Descripcion 
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = from t1 in Table1
             join t2 in Table2
               on new { id = t1.ID; cid = t1.CID } equals new { id = t2.FID: cid = 20} into gr1
             join t3 in Table3
               on t1.GID equals t3.GID into gr2
             from t123 in gr2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new Details (){

             }
          return result.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're discovered, most LINQ providers don't offer support for a `right join`. DefaultIfEmpty translates into a `LEFT join`. As a result, you need to flip the logic of your query around a bit to turn the right join into a left one.

As far as the actual syntax, I've had success adopting more of an ANSI-82 syntax rather than worrying about the `into temp2 from temp3 in temp2` syntax. Something along the lines of:

```
var result = 
    from t3 in Table3
    from t1 in Table1.Where(temp1 => temp1.GID == t3.GID).DefaultIfEmpty()
    join t2 in Table2 on t1ID equals t2.FID
    where t1.CID == 20
    select new Details{};
```